# What does client space mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I am learning programming with Python. Recently i have been reading an article tutoring how to make graphical interface for programs and etc. I came across a sentence which doesn't make sense.

Sentence :

> Here we put the Frame widget, accessed via the self attribute to the Tk root window. It is expanded in both directions. In other words, it takes the whole client space of the root window.

What does client space mean here? I have searched over many dictionaries and the word client either means customer or a PC or Workstation which is using services provided by a server.

I would appreciate so much anyone who could put time and help me. Thanks.

Comment: The space available on the client device (or in the client window) for rendering text and images.

Comment: For "client" see "client-server" or client-server "architecture", which refer to a logical (and sometimes physical) separation of behaviors (or physical components) in a system. A rendering engine might serve data to a client window.  A database engine might serve data to a client process. Etc.  Physical: database server, client workstations. The "client" is the consumer-process or consumer-device.

Comment: As TRomano states, there is a specific definition for "client space", meaning the area Windows or XWindows will relocate as the window is moved, from (0,0) to the window width and height. See https://books.google.com/books?id=cJBWeBVLXAcC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=%22client+space%22++of+a+window&source=bl&ots=Ck98w8C50E&sig=HdwszmDMxEM5MpYSnVnwIysIF8E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=k2bzVIvbINezyASYoYHQCA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22client%20space%22%20%20of%20a%20window&f=false.

Comment: @TRomano : I understood well,thank you very much. based on what you have said " client " means something which uses other thing services. Like a Client window sounds like something which uses OS GUI system services. Am i right?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik : So it sounds like something like " Coordinates of screen" am i right? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are two sets of coordinates commonly used in windowing applications: *screen coordinates*, encompassing the entire display, and *client coordinates*, within each separate window shown on the display. The *client* window may be smaller, the same size, or even larger than the area of the display.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

> As [TRomano states](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51801/what-does-client-space-mean-in-this-context#comment96451_51801), there is a specific definition for "client space", meaning the area Windows or XWindows will relocate as the window is moved, from (0,0) to the window width and height. See books.google.com/…. –  [DrMoishe Pippik](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13999/drmoishe-pippik) [Mar 1 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51801/what-does-client-space-mean-in-this-context#comment96491_51801)